# Selected row from each section of UITableView ( Multiple Selection )

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have used tableview(grouped).

So i need to select one row from the each section of UITableviewSection.

So for that i have tableview and one submit button .So i need to check when i click on the submit button i need to check whether i have selected one row from the each section ,if not then show alert as not selected the section number.How to check?

This is my data.

```
{
    "data":[
              {
               "question": "Gender",
               "options": ["Male","Female"]
              },
              {
               "question": "How old are you",
               "options": ["Under 18","Age 18 to 24","Age 25 to 40","Age 41 to 60","Above 60"]
              },
              {
               "question": "I am filling the Questionnaire for?",
               "options": ["Myself","Mychild","Partner","Others"]
              }
            ]


}
```

QuestionModel:-

```
class QuestionListModel: NSObject {
     var selected = false

    var dataListArray33:[NH_OptionsModel] = []


    var id:Int!
    var question:String!
    var buttontype:String!
    var options:[String]?
    var v:String?

      var optionsModelArray:[OptionsModel] = []
    init(dictionary :JSONDictionary) {

        guard   let question = dictionary["question"] as? String,
            let typebutton = dictionary["button_type"] as? String,

                let id = dictionary["id"] as? Int
             else {
                return

        }



        if let options = dictionary["options"] as? [String]{
            print(options)

           print(options)


            for values in options{

                print(values)

                let optionmodel = OptionsModel(values: values)
                self.optionsModelArray.append(optionmodel)

            }


        }


        self.buttontype = typebutton
        self.question = question
        self.id = id
    //   print(self.dataListArray33)
                   }

}
```

optionModel:-

```
class OptionsModel: NSObject {

    var isSelected:Bool? = false

  var v:String?
        var values:String?



     init(values:String) {

           self.values = values
           print( self.values)

        }
```

ViewModel:-

```
     func numberOfSections(tableView: UITableView) -> Int{
            print((datasourceModel.dataListArray?.count)!)
            return (datasourceModel.dataListArray?.count)!
        }

        func titleForHeaderInSection(atsection section: Int) -> NH_QuestionListModel {
            return datasourceModel.dataListArray![section]
        }

        func numberOfRowsIn(section:Int) -> Int {

            print( datasourceModel.dataListArray?[section].optionsModelArray.count ?? 0)
            return datasourceModel.dataListArray?[section].optionsModelArray.count ?? 0
            // return self.questionsModelArray?[section].optionsModelArray.count ?? 0
        }

        func datafordisplay(atindex indexPath: IndexPath) -> NH_OptionsModel{

            print(datasourceModel.dataListArray![indexPath.section].optionsModelArray[indexPath.row])

            return datasourceModel.dataListArray![indexPath.section].optionsModelArray[indexPath.row]

        }
 func question(answer:String)  {
        print(questions)
        questions.append(answer)
        print(questions )



    }

    func questionlist(answer:String)  {
        print( questionlist )
        questionlist.append(answer)
        print( questionlist )



    }
    func answer(answer:String)  {
      answers.append(answer)
               print(answers)



    }
```

and finally viewController:-

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return questionViewModel.numberOfSections(tableView: tableView)
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {


        let identifier = "HeaderCell"

        var headercell: questionheader! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? questionheader

        if headercell == nil {
            tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "questionheader", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
            headercell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? NH_questionheader
        }

        headercell.setReviewData(reviews:questionViewModel.titleForHeaderInSection(atsection:section))




        return headercell
    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

        return 150

    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return questionViewModel.numberOfRowsIn(section: section)
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let identifier = "Cell"
        var cell: QuestionListCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? QuestionListCell

        if cell == nil {
            tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "QuestionListCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? NH_QuestionListCell
        }
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear


        let questionsModel = questionViewModel.titleForHeaderInSection(atsection:indexPath.section)
        print(questionsModel.buttontype)

        questionViewModel.button = questionsModel.buttontype


        cell.setOptions(Options1: questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath))

         print("Section \(indexPath.section), Row : \(indexPath.row)")


        return cell

    }





    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){


        print("Section \(indexPath.section), Row : \(indexPath.row)")


        let cell = tableview.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? NH_QuestionListCell

        let model = questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath)

        print(model.isSelected)


        cell?.setOptions(OptionsSelected:questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath))
        print(model.isSelected)
        questionViewModel.isselected = model.isSelected!



        let section = indexPath.section
        let index = indexPath.row
        print(section)
        print(index)



        if !questionViewModel.selectedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath) {

            questionViewModel.selectedIndexPaths.append(indexPath)
            print(questionViewModel.selectedIndexPaths.append(indexPath))


            let questionModel = questionViewModel.titleForHeaderInSection(atsection: section)
            print(questionModel.question)


            questionViewModel.question = questionModel.question
            questionViewModel.questionlist(answer: questionViewModel.question!)


            let cell = tableview.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? NH_QuestionListCell

            let model = questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath)
            print(model.values)

            questionViewModel.answer(answer: model.values!)

            let value: Int = questionModel.id
                let string = String(describing: value)
                //let x: Int? = Int(model.id)

            questionViewModel.question_id = string
            questionViewModel.question(answer: questionViewModel.question_id!)

            print(questionModel.id)

            // append the selected index paths
        }       //  if indexPath.section == section {
       //     questionViewModel.indexPath(indexPaths: index)
       // }


            }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {




        if let index = questionViewModel.selectedIndexPaths.index(of: indexPath) {
            print(index)
            questionViewModel.selectedIndexPaths.remove(at: index)
        }



}
```

According to this i got the output .
But i have button action in viewcontroller.

```
@IBAction func forward(_ sender: AnyObject) {
}
```

In this button action i need to check whether from each section did i selected one row or not .if not show alert .How to do

my current didselect method :-

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
 let cell = tableview.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? NH_QuestionListCell

            let model = questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath)

            print(model.isSelected)


            cell?.setOptions(OptionsSelected:questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath))
            print(model.isSelected)
            questionViewModel.isselected = model.isSelected!



            let section = indexPath.section
            let index = indexPath.row
            print(section)
            print(index)


            if !questionViewModel.selectedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath) {

                questionViewModel.selectedIndexPaths.append(indexPath)
                print(questionViewModel.selectedIndexPaths.append(indexPath))


                let questionModel = questionViewModel.titleForHeaderInSection(atsection: section)
                print(questionModel.question)


                questionViewModel.question = questionModel.question
                questionViewModel.questionlist(answer: questionViewModel.question!)


                let cell = tableview.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? NH_QuestionListCell

                let model = questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath)
                print(model.values)

                questionViewModel.answer(answer: model.values!)

                let value: Int = questionModel.id
                    let string = String(describing: value)
                    //let x: Int? = Int(model.id)

                questionViewModel.question_id = string
                questionViewModel.question(answer: questionViewModel.question_id!)

                print(questionModel.id)

                          }
```

I have 3 array 
According to this didselect method:-

ex:-for section 1 :-i selected 1st row so the data append as below.

```
questionlist:["How r u?"]
answelist:["fine"]
```

But suppose i think that i need 2nd indexpath ,so i need to remove the previous appended data from arrays and append the current data .As below:

```
questionlist:["How r u?"]
answelist:["not well"]
```

And next for section 2 : i selected 1st indexpath.row data .then that data is append.So i need to get as below:-

```
 questionlist:["How r u?","Gender"]
    answelist:["not well","Male"]
```

Here selecting i think that i need the 2nd option then remove the added indexpath.row data from array and show as:-

```
 questionlist:["How r u?","Gender"]
        answelist:["not well","Female"]
```

Such way how to set?

Comment: Check on didSelectRow which option in which section is pressed and save the selected option separately as properties. Then you only have to validate if the properties are not nil.

Comment: @FabioBerger i have updated my currently status of the code.In this what should write in the button action ?How to validate?

Comment: @FabioBerger how to implement?

Comment: Save the options for gender, age etc. in a property. In forward just check if none of the properties is empty

Comment: @FabioBerger i have updated

Answer (score 0):

You can store selected indexPath in an array. OnClick of submit just loop through array and check either at least one element is from each section.

FYI : indexPath contains section info also.

Declare an mutable array and allocate in viewDidLoad.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        [anArray addObject:indexPath];

}
```

on Submit action follow this, you can improvise based on your requirement

```
-(void)onSubmitAction{
     [anArray addObject:indexPath];
     NSMutableArray *countOfSection=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (NSIndexPath*indexPath in anArray ) {
      if(![anArray containsObject:indexPath.section])
        [countOfSection addObject:indexPath.section];
      }
      if(countOfSection.count == self.tableview.numberOfSections){
    //write your code
      }else{
    // show alert
   }

  }
```

Comment: I have given sample code in objective C , swift also will go as same . If u still did not got this I would write swift snippet also. Thanks

Comment: here for sections for for 2.But section count based on the data from  the url.so how to do

Comment: You can either save model in array and check the property to find at least any one from every section is selected  or you can do what I suggested. I have given edit for your no of section problem

Answer (score 0):

you can update your model based on the selection like

```
"data":[
              {
              "question": "Gender",
              "options": ["Male","Female"],
              "optionSelected": "Male"

              }
              ]
```

and on Submit , check data for selections

Answer (score 0):

The table view has a property to get selected index paths. You can use all native components for that. What you need is to deselect an item at index path where one is already selected in a certain section. You also just need to then check that the number of selected index paths is the same as number of arrays in your data source.

Check something like this:

```
var dataSource: [[Any]]!
var tableView: UITableView!

func didSelectRowAt(_ indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let selectedPaths = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows else { return } // We need to have selected paths
    guard selectedPaths.contains(indexPath) == false else { return } // The same cell being selected

    let previouslySelectedCellIndexPaths: [IndexPath] = selectedPaths.filter { $0.section == indexPath.section && $0 != indexPath } // Getting all selected index paths within this section
    previouslySelectedCellIndexPaths.forEach { tableView.deselectRow(at: $0, animated: true) } // Deselect waht was previously selected
}

/// Will return array of selected objects only if all sections have a selected index
///
/// - Returns: A result array
func getSelectionData() -> [Any]? {
    guard let selectedPaths = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows else { return nil } // We need to have selected paths
    guard selectedPaths.count == dataSource.count else { return nil } // This should prevent missing selections assuming all index paths are unique in sections
    return selectedPaths.map { dataSource[$0.section][$0.row] } // Map selected index paths back to objects
}
```

I tried to use kind of minimum code to show all of this. It is all commented so you can see row by row what goes on.

You might want to check is all sections are unique the second method but it is not needed if the first one is always used.

Comment: where the didSelectRowAt function should call?

Comment: @clydececiljohn Wherever in a delegate method `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt`. You can even just paste the content of this method into it but careful not to conflict it with your own code.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : Create Global Variable

```
var selectedIndexPaths = [IndexPath]()
```

Step 2: Add UITableView Property

```
tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
```

Step 3 : Implement the delegate methods

```
//On Selection
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)      {


        let selectedIndexPathAtCurrentSection = selectedIndexPaths.filter({ $0.section == indexPath.section})

        for indexPath in selectedIndexPathAtCurrentSection {
            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
            if let indexOf = selectedIndexPaths.index(of: indexPath) {
                selectedIndexPaths.remove(at: indexOf)
            }
        }
        selectedIndexPaths.append(indexPath)


}
// On DeSelection
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if let index = selectedIndexPaths.index(of: indexPath) {
        selectedIndexPaths.remove(at: index)
    }
}
```

Step 4: Getting Selected IndexPaths with sections

```
@IBAction func forward(sender:Any){

      let totalSections = questionViewModel.numberOfSections(tableView: tableView)


       for section in 0..<totalSections {

        if (selectedIndexPaths.filter({ $0.section == section}).count >= 1) {
            continue
        } else {

            // Show alert
            print("Please select item at",(section))
            return
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: here showing ambiguous reference to member tableview(_viewforheaderInSection)How to solve

Comment: i have a problem in this .i have updated some functions in the viewmodel and update the didselect method in the ViewController.please check .So according to your code .The code is fine.

Comment: But i need 3 array.As while selecting the cell i need to append the data in array.And i mention in the didselect method.But here i should able to select only one cell for each cell.Eg:-question 1- In question 1 i selected one option from the options and i append the data.But while i think that i need not want 1st option ,i need to select 2nd option.So i clicked 2nd options.So according to my code here :-2 data will enter.But i need to remove the previous added list and only needed the current selected data .How to do?

Comment: Oh, You mean to say only one cell should be selected from one section and if user wants to select another question(cell) from same section than you should deselect the first cell you selected earlier ?

Comment: oh yes.how to do?

Comment: You'll have to add remove index path from Data Structure ,

Comment: but where this function will call .And it should basec on section.How to deo?

Comment: Update didSelect method , do try it and let me know . Upvote if it's working now

Comment: here showing as variable not available in indexpath .

Comment: here the values are not coming?

Comment: Where values not coming ?

Comment: I have update my question .please check i have mention the latest updated didselect method and the way that the output needed.How to do?